# fb->api me feed post - Youtube video, can't see the thumbnail

Tags: php, facebook

I'm currently working on a facebook page tab application, but I've encountered a problem along the way. When I try to post a Youtube video on a users wall, it shows everything except the thumbnail, that you usually would be able to click and then watch the video directly on the persons timeline.

**My code for creating the timeline story:**

```
<?php

require_once('sdk/facebook.php');

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '331499573565576';
$config['secret'] = 'xxx';
$config['cookie'] = true;

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$post = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array(
    'message' => 'Anvo Test Besked',
    'name' => 'Anvo Test Navn',
    'description' => 'Anvo Test Beskrivelse',
    'caption' => 'Anvo Test Caption',
    'source' =>  'http://www.youtube.com/embed/mhJp9E10gbU',
    'picture' => 'http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/mhJp9E10gbU/default.jpg',
    'link' => 'http://anvo.dk'
));

if($post){
    echo 'It\'s done!';
}else{
    echo 'fail';
}
```

?>

**The problem:**

[image]

Usually you would be able to see the clickable thumbnail to the left, but there is nothing there, however if I remove the source variable from the array, it shows a thumbnail but not one that I am able to click on, since it does not lead to anything.

I've struggled with this problem for about 4 hours now, and searched for anything I thourght would fix the problem, but with no luck.

I really hope that one of you out there can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (not sure about 'name' parameter, changed it to title):

```
$post = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array(
    'message' => 'Anvo Test Besked',
    'title' => 'Anvo Test Navn',
    'description' => 'Anvo Test Beskrivelse',
    'caption' => 'Anvo Test Caption',
    'link' => 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhJp9E10gbU'
));
```